# How to wait only for the first thread in an array to finish in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In Ruby, to wait every thread in an array to finish its work can be done using `Thread#join`:

```
threads = []

threads << Thread.new { sleep 1 }
threads << Thread.new { sleep 5 }
threads << Thread.new { sleep 2 }

# waiting for all work to finish
threads.each(&:join)
```

But what I need to do, is to wait only for the first thread of the array to finish. Once the first is done, I want to stop the execution.

Is there a easy way or built-in way to do so in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a thread-safe way to wait for something to happen in one of several threads, you can use a Queue.

```
queue = Queue.new
threads = []

threads << Thread.new { sleep 2; queue.push(nil) }
threads << Thread.new { sleep 50; queue.push(nil) }
threads << Thread.new { sleep 20; queue.push(nil) }

# wait for one
queue.pop

# clean up the rest
threads.each(&:kill).each(&:join)
```